Problem with Container Analysis API in GCP
I have enabled the Container Analysis API in the GCP project using the following code in Pulumi using TypeScript:
new gcp.projects.Service(`mbadas-${environment}-container-analysis-api`, {
  project: projectId,
  service: 'containeranalysis.googleapis.com',
  disableOnDestroy: false,
});

When I go to my GCP console --> API --> Enabled APIs & Services, then I can also see that API is enabled


When I go to Artifact Registry in GCP console, it is still showing API disabled (see the pic below):

What am I doing wrong here ? Why are the images not being scanned for Vulnerabilities.

For you to perform the scanning, there are 2 APIs need to be enable:

Artifact Registry

Container Scanning API


Then follow through these docs to enable automatic scanning of images vulnerabilities.

Have you checked the Container Scanning API as mentioned ?

Hi !
Thanks for the answer. I just realized that I was missing "Container Scanning API". After enabling this API, the new images in the Artifact Registry are being scanned.
